# ASP.NET WebForms Form Action XSS Vunerability?

Tags: asp.net, xss

I have been working on addressing some vulnerabilities highlighted by the `Acunetix Web Scanner`, in particular those relating to `XSS`.

```
www.mywebsite.com/signed-out/blahblah
```

due to the re-write rules the 'blahblah' is taken as a parameter of a query string, ie.

```
www.mywebsite.com/internal/path/LoggedOut.aspx?reason=blahblah
```

What the tool has noticed is that you can enter `javascript:prompt(919416);` as the `queryString` and `ASP.NET` seems to modify the form action automatically to:

```
<form name="aspnetForm" method="post" action="javascript:prompt(919416);?reason=session-expired%2fjavascript%3aprompt(919416)%3b" id="aspnetForm">
```

Which reflects the input queryString. However:

1. Is this actually executable?
2. I can't seem to find how to stop ASP.NET modifying the form action.

I'm still new to this area, please be gentle! Any help and advice greatly appreciated.

Comment: I found a way to mitigate this issue which was to populate the Form Action in code at the PreRender stage which means ASP.NET isn't auto-populating it, thus solving the problem.